# Android (ListView customAdapter) observer unregistered

Tags: android, listview, adapter, illegalstateexception

I want to update my list, with the same method, I mean, to load the list I have this method and work:

```
public void SeeList(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    listAdapter1 = getListData();
                    customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listAdapter1);
                    user_list.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                    registerForContextMenu(user_list);
                } catch (Exception e) {     }
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            }).start();
}
```

And when I want to refresh the list have the same method as above "seeList ()" for refresh, I try to update the list.

But I jump Error unknown to me.
(How I can resolve this problem ?)

```
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@4e9c7894 was not registered.
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:2638)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12160)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2570)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5145)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:359)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:309)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3535)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I am developing a software for android, but I can not continue. 
It is very urgent.

Comment: How I can refresh "status" from items of the my list?

Comment: did you find answer to this?